# How to set shared variable from "Get"

Tags: parallelization

I load some file by Get, as:
`Get[file.m]`; 
I want that functions from this file will be defied for all Kernels, what I have to do?

Thank you!

Comment: `ParallelEvaluate[Get[file.m]]`? Curiously, there is a `ParallelNeeds` but no `ParallelGet`.

Comment: ... no comments, of course, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `ParallelNeeds` does more than `ParallelEvaluate[Needs[...]]`. It registers that `Needs` command to run on any newly started kernel, even if those kernels are started *after* evaluating the `ParallelNeeds`. The thinking may have been that with such a drastc change to the parallel environment, `file.m` better be a proper package rather than some script.

Comment: What you can also do is apply `DistributeDefinitions` to the stuff in `file.m`. This will be robust against starting new kernels.

Comment: @Henrik Why did you delete your answer? It is the simplest solution, and it's what I would have done (unless I have special requirements—normally I don't keep starting new kernels so making it robust to that is not necessary).

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah okay. I thought it was obsolete now... and a quick blind shot. Anyways, I have just undeleted the answer for not having one more unanswered question hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

*Turning a comment into an answer.*

```
ParallelEvaluate[Get[file.m]]
```